# Cannot navigate Emacs Commands in helm M-x

Tags: helm

I'm trying to comment a region of code in my `init.el` file, so I type `M-x comment-region`

While I see the match I want in `Emacs Commands` Helm actually autocompletes this to `uncomment-region` since this is in my Emacs Commands History.

When I hit /enter/ it replaces my `comment-region` command with an `uncomment-region` command, with the result that I am unable to execute `comment-region` at all.  I cannot navigate the commands in the lower buffer---I can only see it identifies and does not use the comment function.

What am I doing wrong and how can I prevent Helm from auto-incorrecting the command I am trying to execute with `[Enter]` here?

[image: can-only-uncomment]

Answer (score 2):

The problem "can't navigate the buffer" is most likely caused by that you have `helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source` set to `t` - it makes the cursor stay in the history section.  I don't know why would anyone want it, so reset the variable to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

These are the ways I can think of to do it:

1. Start the command with `^` like this: `^comment-region`. This will select commands that **begin** with that substring, automatically selecting `comment-region`.
2. Customize variable `helm-M-x-reverse-history` to `t`. This will switch the order of sections *Emacs Commands history* and *Emacs Commands*, so that `comment-region` will be selected first.
3. Use down arrow (or C-n) to select `comment-region` and press Enter. (*I see that you mention that you can't navigate the buffer, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work in a standard Helm installation.*)
4. If you follow #3, the next time you type `comment-region`, it will be automatically selected since it will be present in the history. No need to follow #1 or #2.